# use concatenation in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel

I want to make my code shorter and I decided to use for loop for many actions

I have `feature_1`, `feature_2` to `feature_10`

so I used this code :

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    <div class="wrapper">

    @if ($product->feature_.$i)
        <li class="ty-compact-list">{{ $product->feature_.$i }} </li>
    @endif
@endfor
```

But it does not work well and just echo number 1 to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.
>
> It is also possible to access class properties using variables within
>   strings using this syntax.

```
<?php
class foo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo "{$foo->$bar}\n";
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
?>
```

So in your case it would be:

```
@for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    <div class="wrapper">
        @if ($product->{"feature_{$i}"})
            <li class="ty-compact-list">{{ $product->{"feature_{$i}"} }} </li>
        @endif
@endfor
```